# What is the best way to stop other users accessing my data, while still allowing them in my Public folder?

Tags: 11.04, encryption, home-directory, folder, shared-folders

I only know of two ways to do this,, encryption and `chomd` and have some questions about those, as well as if there are any other ways.

I want any given user have their data protected from any other user *unless* an administrator password is given. I would also like anyone, without authentication, to be able to view a Public folder.

Is it possible to encrypt a home folder while still allowing the public folder to be accessed?

If not, is it possible to `chomd` the home folder so it's contents cannot be read (files) but navigation to the Public folder is still possible?

Comment: There is no reason why a public folder needs to be in your home directory.  Make another directory somewhere else, like /data, and share it however you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you encrypt your home folder, nobody is able to access your public files without decrypting it first. If you want to allow others to read your public files, but disallow access to other files, you need to revoke any permissions for the others and set the permissions mask to avoid newly created files relaxed permissions.

1. Edit `~/.profile` and change `#umask 022` to `umask 027` (I believe the default is `#umask 002` for Oneiric and up, use `umask 007` in that case). This will suggest to programs that the read, write and execute permission bits are never set for other users.
2. Re-login to apply these changes. This is needed to ensure that the next step will succeed for all files.
3. Remove all of the permission bits for other:

   ```
   chmod -R o-rwx ~
   ```
4. You've successfully removed read, write and execute permissions for the world. Now, add the execute bit again to the home folder so others can descend into it:

   ```
   chmod o+x ~
   ```
5. Allow others to read and descend into your Public folder as well:

   ```
   chmod o+rx ~/Public
   ```
6. Profit!

Comment: Is it possible to set this to happen whenever a new user is created, rather than using user specific directories?

Comment: You can edit the default umask in `/etc/profile`. AFAIK you can create the `Public` folder with default permissions set to 755 in `/etc/skel/`, but I cannot confirm it yet.